# Xamarin Mac minimize to tray on close button

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want change behavior of standard close button of window. When user clicked on it then minimize to tray, not close window. How can I do this?

P.S Here is a small video example of this behavior on Slack application. I want do same[image].

Comment: The window of mac already have minimize button, you can set it on your own https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/user-interface/window

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I need minimize to tray on close button, like Slack app in macOS, you can install it and try click on close button and then app is not close - it minimized

Comment: try disable the close button if you dont need it

Comment: No, I need close button, but close button must minimize app to tray, not close it. I have updated description and record example with Slack app what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the **applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed** method in appdelegate like:

```
public override bool ApplicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(NSApplication sender)
{
return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working solution. Thank you!